# ZipKit and Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, zip

We're trying to set up ZipKit as part of our Xcode 4 project using these [instructions](https://bitbucket.org/kolpanic/zipkit/wiki/UsingZipKit)  and we're having trouble getting our application to compile.

Here's the setup we currently have (as I'm not allowed to post images, I'll just give you the links to them):

[Project Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkOLk.jpg)

All builds are set to go into a shared directory:
[Xcode Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqSJ8.jpg).

When building the app, we get the following error:
**UIUpdateDownloadDialog.m:10:9: fatal error: 'ZKDataArchive.h' file not found [1](https://bitbucket.org/kolpanic/zipkit/wiki/UsingZipKit)**

That line in *UIUpdateDownloadDialog.m* says `#import "ZKDataArchive.h"`.

Any ideas on what we're doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry it took so long to respond, but my schedule has been very hectic.

We managed to get ZipKit working under XCode 4 and be able to build for both the simulator and devices.

Here's how we did it:

1. We opened the Demo project from ZipKit and went all the way down to find the included ZipKit.xcodeproj.
2. Once we had that, we opened our project and [dragged ZipKit into the frameworks folder of our project. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcbYR.png
3. We changed the **build settings** of both the targets in our project (as well as the static library *touchzipkit*) to **Build Active Architecture Only**.

We were then able to build everywhere.

In fact, last night we were about to send the app update to Apple, but when trying to create the archive we got a linking error! But that's a [question on its own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754334/xcode-4-linking-error-when-archiving-application).

Thank you all for trying to help!

Comment: I'm able to build for Device and Simulator, but when I try to archive I get: ZKDefs.h, ZKFileArchive.h No such file or directory.

Comment: You forgot to include the header search path to where those files are.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a ZipKit framework - try adding that to your project instead of the whole project and importing like so:

```
#import <ZipKit/ZipKit.h>
```

The other alternative is to try adding the Zipkit directory to the include path, though having ZipKit as sub-project should include all the classes and header files.

Comment: The framework is for Mac OS X use only, according to this: [link](https://bitbucket.org/kolpanic/zipkit/wiki/Home).

Comment: I see - I was getting the framework just from the list of files he displayed in his image.  I just added another possibility, you could try adding the header directory to the include path.